# Any C++ libraries for verb/action command line interfaces?

Tags: c++, command-line

As the title implies I'm trying to find a library (header only would be nice) that makes it easy to implement these nifty little command line interfaces you see in web applications that have the form:

```
$ application --general-flag=asdf action --action-specific-flag=asdf positional --more-flags
```

For example:

```
$ hugo new site --force --format=toml mysite
```

or

```
$ hugo --buildDrafts
```

For Go there are some (in my opinion) very good libraries for this, e.g. [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) or kingpin (github.com/alecthomas/kingpin).
However, I was not able to find a similar library in c++ that I like.
Most solutions seems to be rather complex to use, verbose or still require lots of manual work.

Generally it seems like they're approaching the problem by looking
at how to parse arguments and options instead of how to build a command
line interface.

Templated ones sometimes rely on RTTI being enabled, which has to be disable in my application.
The ones I looked at are: [tclap](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/), optionparser (optionparser.sourceforge.net/), cmdline (github.com/tanakh/cmdline), args.hxx (github.com/Taywee/args).

Args.hxx looked the most promising but relies on RTTI.
Do you know any libraries that I might have overlooked? Also sorry for the links, I was not allowed to have more than 2 but still wanted to give some info on what I already tried.

Comment: Requests for resources such as libraries are not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your purpose. Are you looking for some functionality for parsing **command-line** argument

Answer (score 0):

Although I never personally used it, you can have a look at [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options.html). I'm not sure if RTTI is needed however.